# Finding angle between a moving tangent and a fixed point

Tags: geometry

Actually, this is a part of a physics question I was recently solving.

Here's what I've come to.

There's an arbitrary point in a circle of radius (say, r). We need to find the minimum angle the line joining a point on the circumference of the circle makes with the tangent drawn at that point.

Originally, I've come to the point where I need to find the point at which the vector (velocity vector, in this case) has its component maximum along the line joining the point and the initial arbitrary point.

I know that the question might sound a bit confusing, but please try to understand it and hint me the solution. Hints to the solution would be fine.

Comment: "There's an arbitrary point in a circle of radius (say, r)." Should that be "on a circle"?

Comment: @Semiclassical Not at all! The point is inside the circle.

Comment: Okay, so you choose an arbitrary point P inside the circle and join it with an arbitrary point Q on the periphery of the circle to form line $l$. Then you define line $m$ to be the tangent to the circle at Q.. And then you want to find the (smaller) angle between these two lines? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Lovsovs Exactly, yes! Do you want the actual physics question I'm solving?

Comment: That would be nice (you can edit your question to include it)!

Answer (score 1):

Let your circle be centered at the origin. Let the point on the periphery be $Q=r\pmatrix{\cos \theta \\ \sin \theta}$ and the point inside the circle be $P=\pmatrix{x_0 \\ y_0}$.

A vector parallel to the tangent at $Q$ will then be $r_1=\pmatrix{-\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta}$, and a vector along the line from $P$ to $Q$ will be $r_2=\pmatrix{x_0-r\cos \theta \\y_0- r\sin \theta}$.

The angle $\phi$ between these vectors are given as

$$\cos \phi=\frac{r_1 \cdot r_2}{|r_1||r_2|}=\frac{y_0\cos \theta-x_0\sin\theta}{|r_2|},$$

where $$|r_2|=\sqrt{(x_0-r \cos \theta)^2+(y_0-r\sin\theta)^2}=\sqrt{r^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-2r(x_0 \cos \theta+y_0\sin \theta)},$$

which can then be solved for $\phi$. This unfortunately cannot be simplified any further - for that, we would have to know more about $P$ and $Q$.